# Is there any method to call class member functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Is there any method that I can call display function of Purchase class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Purchase
{
private:
string userName;
int countOfItems;  
float amount;
float static totalAmt;
int static totalCountOfItems;

public:

void display(Purchase obj[],int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        setTotalAmt(obj[i].getTotalAmt()+obj[i].getAmount());
        setCountOfItems(obj[i].getCountOfItems()+obj[i].getCountOfItems());
    }
    cout<<"Total Amount Received :"<<getTotalAmount();
    cout<<"Total Number of Items sold :"<<getTotalCountOfItems();
}
};
```

getters and setter are already member functions.

How can i call display function in main function
My main function looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Purchase.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    string userName;
    int countOfItems;  
    float amount;
    cout<<"Enter the Number of customers :";
    cin>>n;
    Purchase P[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter the Name of the customer :";
        getline(cin,userName);
        P[i].setUserName(userName);
        cout<<"Enter the No of Items purchased :";
        cin>>countOfItems;
        P[i].setCountOfItems(countOfItems);
        cout<<"Enter the purchase amount :";
        cin>>amount;
        P[i].setAmount(amount);
    }
    cout<<"Purchase Details :";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Customer "<<i+1<<" :"<<P[i].getUserName()<<endl;
        cout<<"No of Items purchased :"<<P[i].getCountOfItems()<<endl;
        cout<<"Purchase amount :"<<P[i].getAmount()<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

At last i have to add calling of display function so that i can add amount and countofitems of every object.

Comment: Are you looking for a [static method](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, because calling memberfunctions is so basic in C++ that it's impossible not to be covered by whatever you're using for learning.

Comment: No, this is a question asked in ```https://app.e-box.co.in/``` i cannot change the signature. all I can change is definition of display and main function.

Comment: Spend several days in reading more about [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/)

Comment: `Purchase P[n];` use VLA **extension**, and so is invalid C++, use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any method to call class member functions?

You could take the address of a member [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) and pass that later.

But with C++11 or better (read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), the C++11 standard), please read [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) then consider using [lambda-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Of course use [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) and [`<functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional)  standard headers.

Take also time to read more about standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

> ```
> void display(Purchase obj[],int n)
> ```

Why can't you use a `void display_vect(std::vector<Purchase>&vec);` ? If you cannot change the API of `display`, consider calling your `display_vect` from your `display` member function.

Read about the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).

Comment: I cannot change signature of a function.

Comment: You can introduce wrapping functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what the issue is, or what you've been asked to do. But it's clear that `display` should not be a member function of `Product`. Member function of `Product` should be concerned with one particular product but `display` is printing all products, so it should be a stand-alone functon not a member function. Your code should look like this

```
class Product
{
    ...
};

void display(Purchase obj[],int n)
{
    ...
}
```

Then calling it from `main` is trivial.

```
int main()
{
    ...
    display(P, n);
}
```